# An inequality for Holder norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $f$ be a non-negative $C^2$ function on a compact domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb R^n$. I am trying to prove the inequality

$$\|\sqrt f\|_{C^{0,1}(\Omega)}\leq C(1 + \|f\|_{C^{1,1}(\Omega)})$$

where $C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$ denotes the Holder space. It seems like this should be a consequence of the mean value theorem and/or the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I am not seeing an elementary proof of this nature. Any suggestions?

Comment: Jensen's Inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect. For example, let $n=1$, $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x$. Then $\|\sqrt{f}\|_{C^{0,1}(\Omega)}=\infty$.

Comment: Does the inequality hold if $M$ is instead assumed to be a compact manifold?

Comment: @user15464: If you mean $M$ is compact without boundary, I think so.  The problem here is that the zero of $f$ is located at the boundary of $\Omega$. If $f(x)=0$ for some interior point $x$, then since $f\ge 0$, $f'(x)=0$, so $\sqrt{f}$ is well behaved around $x$.

Comment: Can you give an outline of a proof?

Comment: @user15464: Sorry, my last comment was misleading. I think in your inequality, $C$ is supposed to be dependent only on $\Omega$ or $M$. Then the inequality fails even when $M$ is a compact manifold without boundary.